# How to view cyrillic URL in Google Analytics using Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics

I'm new to Google analytics and because my website URL are Cyrillic in Google analytic I see page path like this:

`/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8`

is there anything I can do to see this URL as: `/спалня/спални-комплекти`?

Comment: Related: [How can I make Google Analytics understand URL encoding?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/how-can-i-make-google-analytics-understand-url-encoding)

Comment: Related: [Google Data studio encode my Arabic titles in landingpage reports table](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121307/google-data-studio-encode-my-arabic-titles-in-landingpage-reports-table)

Comment: Similar questions don't have good answers, but your question is in the right place now, and hopefully somebody will be able to answer you.